# Error with Eclipse and Tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

i have this kind of error when I Run server on Index.html and try to register:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gds1v.png)[Eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WG7aQ.png)

How can I do to resolve this problem? I want to create a simple web application in which I can do a register and login form. 
Thanks you a lot.
This is my code:

**index.html**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>WebSite</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Site</h1>
<br>
Welcome in the site:
<br>
<a href="createuser.html">Register</a>!
</body>
</html>
```

**createuser.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="CreateUser.do">
First name: <input type="text" size="40" maxlength="40" name="firstname" required="required"/><br>
Last name:  <input type="text" size="40" maxlength="40" name="lastname" required="required"/><br>
Login: <input type="text" size="40" maxlength="40" name="login" required="required">
Password:    <input type="password"  name="password" required="required" /><br> <input type="SUBMIT" value="create">  
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

**useradd.jsp**

```
        <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>New User Created</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
    First Name: <% String fName = request.getParameter("firstname"); out.print(fName); %>
    Last Name: <% String lName = request.getParameter("lastname"); out.print(lName); %>
    Login: <% String logI = request.getParameter("login"); out.print(logI); %>
    Password: <% String psw = request.getParameter("password"); out.print(psw); %> 
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

**AddUser.java**

```
    import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
@WebServlet("/CreateUser.do")
public class AddUser extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public AddUser() {
        super();

    }
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WebContent/useradd.jsp");
        view.forward(request, response);    
    }
}
```

Comment: If you prefer the code in pastebin: https://pastebin.com/0ANhXEN6

Comment: Can you verify that useradd.jsp is being deployed in the right place?

Comment: Try calling Sito/useradd.jsp

Comment: At the begining of the post i put the Eclipse image. I put the file with the others one ( only java in src folder)

Comment: I try now to change in /Sito/useradd.jsp but I have the same error

Comment: How are you launching the server?

Comment: Yes I lunch the server